# Trouble at Setting Up Webserver

Tags: networking, webserver, webmin, ddns

I decided to use a Raspberry Pi (with Raspbian) as a home webserver and NAS. I have installed on it Apache, Owncloud and Samba (for an easier approach for accessing files inside home). I also installed webmin to make easier set up and maintenance. The Raspberry Pi is connected to a router, which is connected in a cable modem in bridge mode. From inside LAN, everything is working fine. Since I have Dynamic IP, I signed in a DDNS service.

The problem arises when I try to access the web server from outside. Using the domain name chosen, I cannot reach the web server. Curiously thought, when I enter `https://mydomainname.net:10000`, I reach the webmin web interface.

What I did already tried on my router

- Set up port forwarding in router for ports 80 and 443
- Configure apache to listen ports 8080 and 4433 and enabling set up port forwarding on these ports
- Set up port triggering of ports 8080 -> 80 and 4433 -> 443 and enabling port for these ports plus for 80 and 443
- Everything above plus DMZ enabled for the Raspberry Pi

Notice that on my router, I do not have port forwarding for port `10000`. However,  PC Flank’s tests report port `10000` open. I also tried changing the port for webmin and I could notice on `pcflank` the open port changing.

This makes me suspect is some configuration on Raspberry Pi. I imagined it could be a firewall, but webmin reports that the Linux Firewall is disabled. So, what I am missing?

Comment: Your router might be using port 80, or you may have a port block. Its always a good idea to test with a wierd, uncommon port first.

Comment: Using DMZ may also be the problem.  DMZ is basically saying forward ALL ports from outside to this internal IP.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I disabled DMZ as per @Tyson suggestion. I also discovered webmin interface was not changing the webserver ports correctly. This answer helped me set apache on ports 20080 and 20443: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940909/configure-apache-to-listen-on-port-other-than-80. However, I still do not understand why my setup of port triggers did not work.

Comment: Are you sure you need port triggering?  I've forwarded incoming ports many times to gain access from the outside, but I have yet to need port triggering for this activity.

Comment: I do not really need it. I was just curious for why I needed to reconfigure apache ports and not simply configure my router to redirect calls on ports 20080 and 20443 to 80 and 443 respectively (I need this since my ISP blocks the default ports)

Comment: I don't think you need to reconfigure the apache ports at all.  I do this all the time leaving port 80 and 443 alone on the rPi.   I think you overcomplicated this.

Comment: As I said, my ISP blocks the ports 80 and 443, so I can't simply portforward them to apache. The options are use port triggering to redirect calls of unblocked ports to the ones Apache was listening (and I do not know why it did not worked) or follow Journeyman suggestion of trying weird ports (which works and for a home web server seens enough).

Comment: You're not getting it.  Your isp blocks 80 and 443, but you aren't using those outside.  The ONLY thing you need to do forward external_ip:20080 to local_ip:80 and external_ip:20443 to local_ip:443.   forget port triggering and DMZ, you don't need either.  You don't need to change the ports on the PI either, your router is doing the translation for you.   If you WANT to change the ports on the PI from 80 to 20080 and 443 to 20443 then fine change them, but then forward 20080 to 20080 and 20443 to 20443.   You are way over complicating this and confusing yourself.

Comment: @Tyson You are right. Your answer made me do some more research and I discovered I was understanding the way that port triggering worked completely wrong. Very much thank you. And thanks for your patience as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I solved my original problem and no one answered my question, I'm going to answer it.

The problem turned out to be an outdated firmware in my router (TP-Link TL-WR841N) that did not have the option to set an internal port in its port forwarding configuration page. A newer release does have this option though, so a simple firmware update enabled me to set up port forwarding correctly without the need to mess up with port triggering and DMZ.